# Error initializing GUI objects; display disabled. error: Couldn’t open images\logo.png

Tags: pygame

I am getting the following error whenever I try to run the file agent.py(https://github.com/kunaldesai97/Smart-Cab/blob/master/smartcab/agent.py)

`Simulator._init_(): Error initializing GUI objects; display disabled. error: Couldn’t open images\logo.png`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces this error. Check if the path and image names are correct and that the image actually exists.

Comment: Yeah, I have shared the link to the code.

Comment: That's not a minimal example, that's your whole project. Nobody here wants to read so much code. You should at least post the complete traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to post a minimal code for this problem. This error is generated whenever an object of class Simulator is created from the agent file. Can you please have a look at this Simulator class. Here's the link: https://github.com/kunaldesai97/Smart-Cab/blob/master/smartcab/simulator.py. I've posted the complete traceback above in the description.

Comment: Remove the `try` and the two `except`s in the `__init__` method and then post the complete traceback. BTW, don't use such broad exceptions as `except Exception`, since they make code harder to debug. There's probably something wrong with the path, but I don't see what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you start the program by running `agent.py` (inside the `smartcab` directory), you need to use this path: `os.path.join("..", "images", "logo.png")`.